# Magento EE database has no triggers

Tags: mysql, magento

I inherited a heavily-customized Magento EE project that has been through multiple stages of disaster. The production database has never been pulled down to lower environments in the roughly two years of the project. It appears the production database has no triggers defined, but all the lower databases (dev, test, etc), do have triggers, which is what you'd expect in a Magento EE project.

At this point I'm not even sure how the application is still running on production. I'm loading a triggerless mysqldump that I took from prod into another environment now to see if the database actually works.

Has anybody ever seen this before? How would this even happen? Maybe the project started out on CE and then was upgraded to EE and the upgrade failed partially? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Do whatever, I would move it myself but can't figure out how.

Comment: You would just edit the question here, copy the contents, and then paste into a new question there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this was caused by the upgrade path from CD to EE, and I guess the previous consultants hacked the upgrade process to not create triggers, or it failed and they didn't notice. Triggers are only necessary if you're reindexing via cron job, not after save, so the app still runs ok.